# Ternary operators in C, wrong output

Tags: c, operators, conditional-operator

I have the bellow code that is asking to identify any errors:

```
main( )
{
int kk = 65 ,ll ;
ll = ( kk == 65 : printf ( "\n kk is equal to 65" ) : printf ( "\n kk is not equal to 65" ) ) ;
printf( "%d", ll ) ;
}
```

I have corrected it to the bellow:

```
int main( )
{
int kk = 65, ll ;
ll = kk == 65 ? printf ( "\n kk is equal to 65" ) : printf ( "\n kk is not equal to 65" );
printf( "%d", ll ) ;
}
```

I would expect the output to be kk is equal to 65, however, I am  getting 'kk is equal to 6519'

Can anyone please have a look into this and help me see the reason for this?

Thank you very much,

Cris G

Comment: `printf( "%d", ll ) ;` What do you expect that to print and have you factored that into what you expect the output to be? Suggest adding a `\n` to the end of each of your `printf` strings to make the output clearer for yourself.

Comment: Always make it a habit to use ***trailing*** newlines when you print with `printf`. Not only would it help understand the issue here, but it also could help you in other places as well, because when `stdout` (which is the stream where `printf` writes) is connected to a terminal or console, it will be *line buffered*. That means the buffered output will be actually written on newline. With leading newline you print the *previous* line, with trailing you print the *current* line.

Answer (score 3):

The `printf()` function returns the number of characters printed to `stdout`. Therefore, the value 19 is assigned to the variable ll. The expression `"\n kk is equal to 65"` is printed on the screen, followed by the value of the variable `ll`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    int kk = 65, ll;
    ll = (kk == 65) ? printf( "\n kk is equal to 65" ) : printf ( "\n kk is not equal to 65" );
    
    printf("\nll: %d", ll);
    printf("\nNumber of character: %d", printf( "\n kk is equal to 65" ));

    return 0;
}
```

This program generates the following output:

```sh
 kk is equal to 65
ll: 19
 kk is equal to 65
Number of character: 19
```

Answer (score 0):

The `" kk is not equal to 65"` part comes from the `printf("\n kk is equal to 65")`and the `"19"` comes from the result of the previous mentioned `printf` which returns 19 as the number of characters written by `printf` for the string `"\n kk is equal to 65"`.